# 'unrecognized selector' error happens when creating a subclass that inherits from NSWindow

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, unrecognized-selector, macos-ventura

I want create a SettingWindow class which inherits from NSWindow, the code works fine in compile stage.

But when execute `let settingWindow = new SettingWindow()`, below error happens.

> -[SettingWindow windowWithContentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1557574f0

This is sample code.

```swift
import Cocoa

final class SettingWindow: NSWindow {
    static let shared = SettingWindow()

    private let tabViewController: NSTabViewController

    private init() {
        tabViewController = NSTabViewController()
        tabViewController.tabStyle = .toolbar
        tabViewController.title = "Setting"

        super.init(contentViewController: tabViewController)
    }
}
```

I also try the code below, it just works. This make me confused.

```swift
import Cocoa

final class SettingWindow: NSWindow {
    static let shared = SettingWindow()

    private let tabViewController: NSTabViewController

    private init() {
        tabViewController = NSTabViewController()
        tabViewController.tabStyle = .toolbar
        tabViewController.title = "Setting"

        super.init(contentRect: .zero, styleMask: [.titled, .closable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        contentViewController = tabViewController
    }
}
```

I'm new to Swift and macOS develop, I want why this happen.

Comment: In your examples you use a convenience initialiser in the first one but a designated  initialiser in the second example and you should _not_ call a superclass convenience initialiser from a subclass, only a designated initialiser. For a more thorough explanation see the [Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/initialization) chapter of the Swift Programming Language Book

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks a lot. Xcode gives no prompt, so I just think it's fine.